# CSS header pushes down banner after CSS fix

Tags: html, css

I messed up and developed my whole layout around two CSS errors (that I know of) and now when I correct the two mistakes I get a broken layout.

Working with errors: http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/index.html CSS: http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/styles/blue.css

Broken with the fix: http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/index3.html CSS: http://jordan.rave5.com/tmpstuff/styles/blue2.css

Notice in the code below there is no semicolon on the `min-height` attributes. That's the mistake I made. When I fix them, the whole thing gets messed up. I've tried removing all code below the mistake but that does nothing, so something even further down may be the problem but I'm not sure.

```css
#header-image-grad {
    z-index: 300;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 174px
    min-width: 1024px;
    max-height: 445px;
    background-image: url(../images/gray-trans.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
}

#header-image-border {
    z-index: 400;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 453px;
    min-height: 174px
    min-width: 1024px;
    max-height: 453px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    background-image: url(../images/border.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question but by removing `min-height: 174px` in the `#header-image-grad` selector the second broken layout matches the first example (Chrome OS X)

Comment: Let me try that, I tried removing beyond it, as the min-height should be active, just not beyond it.

Comment: Interesting. My understanding if you DIDN't close the property it'd null what's after it. Good to know. Thank you @acowley

Comment: @WASasquatch If you inspect the element with Chrome dev tools it shows the broken property. Pleased to help.